# Angular 2: Problems with imports not finding modules

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

In our Ionic 2 + Angular 2 project, we had a folder "profile" in which we had "profile.html" and "profile.ts", and in the latter, we had three components which are two modals and a dialog.

As the file "profile.ts" was so big with these components, I moved two of them (the other was tiny and made sense in that same file), all to specific files in the same folder: "profileEdit.ts", "hobbiesDialog.ts", resulting in this folder tree:

$project/src/pages/profile

- profile.ts
- profile.html
- profileEdit.ts
- profileEDit.html
- profile.scss
- hobbiesDialog.ts   (the template is coded inside)

So now, my profile.ts has these imports:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ViewController, PopoverController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AlertController, ToastController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import  Parse from 'parse';

import { LoginPage } from '../login/login';
import { ProfileEditModal } from 'profileEdit';
```

The last one is failing: somehow, Angular can't find the module:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "profileEdit"
>       at eval

I also added these modules to the app.module.ts:

```
// more imports
import { ProfilePage, ProfilePopover } from '../pages/profile/profile';
import { ProfileEditModal } from '../pages/profile/profileEdit';
import { HobbiesPopover } from '../pages/profile/hobbiesDialog';
```

Also added them in the declarations and entryComponents arrays of @NgModule.

... but it won't work! It used to work when it was in a single file, but now it doesn't. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you import a class which is at the same directory level, you should import it like

```
'./fileName.extension'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try 
`import { ProfileEditModal } from './profileEdit';`